# How to handle dynamic graph with GNN networks?

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

At present, I need to use GNN to deal with dynamic graphs, and the graph structure of each input is different. What should I do about it? My goal is to use GNN for regression. Anyone help?